# Can't get SID from DACL

Tags: winapi, sid

I am trying to get the DACL of service, and then get the SIDs. Here is my code:

```
  PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd = NULL;

  DWORD dwSize         = 0;
  DWORD dwBytesNeeded  = 0;
  BOOL bDaclPresent   = FALSE; // tu Trua mashin aq DACL
  PACL pacl           = NULL;
  BOOL bDaclDefaulted = FALSE;
  PEXPLICIT_ACCESS bevri = NULL;
  ULONG aq = 0;

  char ** gio = NULL;

  serviceManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);

  SC_HANDLE me = OpenService(serviceManager, serviceName, READ_CONTROL);

  if (serviceManager == NULL)
  {
     fprintf(fp, "OpenService: fail %d\n.\n", GetLastError());
     fflush(fp);
  }

  if (!QueryServiceObjectSecurity(me, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &psd, 0, &dwBytesNeeded))
    {
      if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
          dwSize = dwBytesNeeded;
          psd = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSize);

          if (psd == NULL)
            {
              fprintf(fp, "HeapAlloc failed\n");
              fflush(fp);
            }
  
          if (!QueryServiceObjectSecurity(me, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, psd, dwSize, &dwBytesNeeded))
            {
              fprintf(fp, "QueryServiceObjectSecurity failed %d\n", (int)GetLastError());
              fflush(fp);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
          fprintf(fp, "QueryServiceObjectSecurity failed %d\n", (int)GetLastError());
          fflush(fp);
        }
    }

  if (!GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(psd, &bDaclPresent, &pacl, &bDaclDefaulted))
  {
    fprintf(fp, "GetSecurityDescriptorDacl failed %d\n", (int)GetLastError());
    fflush(fp);
  }

  if (GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl(pacl, &aq, &bevri) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    fprintf(fp, "GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl:  failed %d.\n", (int)GetLastError());
    fflush(fp);
  }

  for (ULONG i = 0; i < aq; i++)
  {
    if (ConvertSidToStringSid(&bevri->Trustee.ptstrName[GetTrusteeForm(&bevri->Trustee)], gio) == 0)
    {
          fprintf(fp, "ConvertSidToStringSid:  failed %d.\n", (int)GetLastError());
          fflush(fp);
    }

    for (int index = 0; gio[index] != NULL; index++) 
      {
        char * myString = gio[index];
        fprintf(fp, "Value: %s\n",myString);
      }
  }
```

I've read in documentation that `GetTrusteeForm`  function would indicate if Trustee has SID or name, it returned `0`s which in `TRUSTEE_FORM`  indicates to `TRUSTEE_IS_SID`.
 My problem is that I have `ConvertSidToStringSid:  failed 87.` which is `The parameter is incorrect.`. I can't figure out why am I getting this.
 **P.S.** I'm sorry I know that this part of code is not really helpful to reproduce the issue, but I thought someone might knew what would problem be. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: use `ConvertSidToStringSid(bevri->Trustee.ptstrName, &gio)  - `bevri->Trustee.ptstrName` is *SID* pointer and free gio by `LocalFree` - however code to complex and not optimal. and gio must be `char*` not `char**`

Comment: you not need `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl` at all. can use direct `AceCount` from *ACL* and enumerate *ACE* also direct or by [`GetAce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446634(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY` - for what this flag ? absolute not need. and small structures more easy and effective allocate by [_alloca](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb1s57t5.aspx) or [_malloca](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5471dc8s.aspx)